# How to make Dict of Ngram of my dataframe start with some string Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, n-gram

I have `dataframe` like this

```
id  name        cat     subcat
-------------------------------
1   aa bb cc    A       a-a
2   bb cc dd    B       b-a
3   aa bb ee    C       c-a
4   aa gg cc    D       d-a
```

I want to make `dict` of this `dataframe` Which includes the most `Ngram` of two words like this

```
aa bb : 2
bb cc : 2
cc dd : 1
bb ee : 1
aa gg : 1
gg cc : 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update using pairwise [recipe from itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

pd.Series(chain(*df['name'].str.split(' ')
                           .apply(lambda x: pairwise(x))))\
  .value_counts()
```

Output:

```
(aa, bb)    2
(bb, cc)    2
(cc, dd)    1
(bb, ee)    1
(aa, gg)    1
(gg, cc)    1
dtype: int64
```

---

IIUC, you can try something like this:

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

pd.Series(list(chain(*df['name'].str.split(' ')
                                .apply(lambda x: list(combinations(x, 2))))))\
  .value_counts()
```

Output:

```
(aa, bb)    2
(aa, cc)    2
(bb, cc)    2
(bb, dd)    1
(cc, dd)    1
(aa, ee)    1
(bb, ee)    1
(aa, gg)    1
(gg, cc)    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Actually, looking at this answer this morning, we should use the "pairwise" recipe from itertools insteads of combinations.